# Maven: How do you deal with dependencies that are both direct and transitive?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to determine an approach to the following situation:

There are 3 Maven artifacts: A, B, and C.

B depends on A. (i.e. it uses some of A's code)

C depends on both A and B (i.e. it uses some of A's code and B's code).

Assume I want to use the same version of A for both B and C.

What approach should be used?

1) Declare A as a dependency in C's pom.xml.

Pro: It's clear to the developer that C depends on A.
Con: If A's version changes, it needs to be updated in multiple places. (both B and C)

2) Don't declare A as a dependency in C's pom.xml.

Pro/Con: Opposite of option 1.

Comment: Typo: I guess you mean `C depends on both A and B` when you said, "C depends on both A and C"

Comment: You're right. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Declare A as a dependency in C's pom.xml.

> The dependency is readable
> Dependency is flexible. If you want to remove A's dependency from B, you do not need to think of the projects that dependend on B.
> As suggested in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662011/maven-how-do-you-deal-with-dependencies-that-are-both-direct-and-transitive/4662446#4662446), that it is a good practice to write down direct dependencies in pom.xml and let maven handle it.

2) Don't declare A as a dependency in C's pom.xml.

> Mostly, no developer going to see pom.xml. And if they want they can see it by using `mvn dependency:tree` and it will show transitive dependency.
> There will be single point of change when a new version of A is released. If you define dependency at more than one place, you may forget to update all the places. In that case, Maven automatically uses the latest one. But, it does sting sometimes. 
> Some people prefer this because, mostly, this type of dependency is common knowledge (e.g. `MyWebApp -> MyWebAppLib -> MySharedLib` and `MyWebApp -> MySharedLib`)  and they want to avoid added step of updating versions at multiple places on each release.

I have written down pros-and-cons, you should evaluate what suits you the best yourself.

---

*Edit#1:* tsk! I have switched my comments.
*Edit#2:* updated the answer after a discussion done on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662011/maven-how-do-you-deal-with-dependencies-that-are-both-direct-and-transitive/4662446#4662446).

Comment: @Jin Kim I have misread the options. So, I had commented in wrong order. Fixed it.

Comment: By option (A), you mean option (1)?

Comment: @Jin Kim I have updated the post to make some-sense, I had your options pasted wrong, earlier.

Comment: (-1) Robin's answer is better IMHO

Comment: @Damien , @Jin Kim -- Updated my answer after a discussion with @Robin

Comment: @Nishant OK, I removed my -1 but I don't give you +1 because I still prefer Robin's answer, clearly stating that first option is better. That might just be a personal preference though.

Comment: @Damien that's reasonable. One of our project still follows (2). And never been a mess-up.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should have all direct dependencies declared in your pom.  Transitive dependencies are just a convenience for automagically resolving your dependencies dependencies.

If you change a version of a direct dependency, the transitive dependencies will likely change along with it, and thus potentially breaking the module.  The module should build as an independent unit and thus should have well defined dependencies that will not break due to external changes.

I disagree that this violates the DRY principal, as maven defines things within the confines of a single project and its pom.  And within this scope there is no repetition.

**Update:**
The reliance on transitive dependencies existing makes the project frail on it's own, and may also lead to more complex issues like when to include it.

For example, if C has a compile dependency on A, but a runtime dependency on B, then you now have to either add the dependency (since it is no longer in your build path) or declare B as compile even though it isn't.  There is a lot to be said for clarity.  Explicitly define what your dependencies are and what their scope is, and expect your dependencies to do the same.  For the most part, your dependency is a black box, until it causes problems and you have to open it.

Comment: Having two version of same artifact/jar in classpath is likely to create a mess(Jar-hell). It is very likely that you want to have single version in both the dependent projects (B and C). If you want to update the version of A either you will have to update the same thing in two POMs (repetition) or there might be a versioning issue. That's why I mentioned DRY.

Comment: C in fact depends on A and it should be stated explicitly. The transitive dependency `C -> B -> A` is an implementation detail of B and is subject to change. You shouldn't know or care about it. In reality that *can* lead to Jar version hell, but it should be part of Maven, given its position in the toolchain, to warn about and help resolve such issues.

Comment: @Nishant - I let maven handle resolving the jars, it doesn't put two in the classpath, it determines which one to put in.  As I said, the projects are independent and should be configured as such.  The reliance on transitive dependencies simply obfuscates what your dependencies actually are which makes them harder to manage, not easier, since the project becomes more fragile due to external changes.

Comment: ah, alright. I see what you're saying. Yes, you will have higher version of the artifact, maven will do it for you.