# With Maven 2, should dependencies be redeclared if they are accessible transitively?

Tags: java, maven-2

I commonly find myself in the situation where a dependency needed in a top level module is available because one of the modules it depends on has the same dependency.

For example:

```
my-module
+- spring-core
   \- commons-logging
```

So assuming I am happy with the version of the transitive dependency, should the depdency, in this case on `commmons-logging`, be redeclared as follows:

```
my-module
+- spring-core
|  \- commons-logging
\- commons logging
```

Or should I just accept the dependency will be obtained transitively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: How do you deal with dependencies that are both direct and transitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662011/maven-how-do-you-deal-with-dependencies-that-are-both-direct-and-transitive)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662011/maven-how-do-you-deal-with-dependencies-that-are-both-direct-and-transitive#4662446

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO it is better to declare it explicitly, so that you can have control over the exact version you use. Otherwise the actual version used can silently change whenever another dependency is updated or a new, seemingly unrelated dependency is introduced, which transitively depends on a newer version of the other library.

Comment: Given that, once released, modules should not change, would this problem occur?  In the example I gave, I'd be tied to a particular version of `spring-core` and by implication a particular version of `commons-logging`.  Only when I upgraded to a newer version of `spring-core` would I potentially get a newer version of `commons-logging` right?

Comment: @Nick, yes. Or when including a new dependency into your project.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think that while Maven does a great job of managing dependencies, if does make it a little to easy to add them, which if you're not careful can have some interesting side effects with your classpath.  Guess the various goals provided by the dependency plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) are you friend when adding dependencies.

Comment: @PéterTörök but what if you are using something like Spring Boot Starter, which is managing the dependency versioning for you? Isn't it okay to  not re-declare in the POM the dependency and just the ones pulled in transitively?

Answer (score 1):

I usually leave them transitively.

It might make sense when you want to override a specific version. For example if spring-core for example needs a commons-logging with version 1.25 and you needs (for various reasons) a 1.26 and they are compatible you should ignore the commons-logging dependency from spring-core and declare your version in your pom.

The same when there is a conflict between two others.